# Understanding Part of Recursive Implementation of MergeSort C++

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am struggling to get my mind around the following recursive implementation of mergesort in C++

What gets me is that since the vector is being passed by reference and vec.clear() is being called, how does that not wipe out the vector even after some of the merging has been done. For example, when the base is hit, the function returns the top frame on the stack and proceeds bak down the stack. However, the function needs to merge more than once and before each merge the vector is being cleared, which I would think means the space in memory (since it is pass by reference) is cleared out and we lose what was already merged? I can understand how this method would work if it was passed by value, but this is passed by reference so I am confused.

```
void merge(vector<int> &final, vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right) {
    while (left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0) {
        if (right.size() == 0) {
            final.push_back(left.at(0));
            left.erase(remove(left.begin(), left.end(), left.at(0)), left.end());
        }
        else if (left.size() == 0) {
            final.push_back(right.at(0));
            right.erase(remove(right.begin(), right.end(), right.at(0)), right.end());
        } else if (left.at(0) <= right.at(0)) {
            final.push_back(left.at(0));
            left.erase(remove(left.begin(), left.end(), left.at(0)), left.end());
        } else if (right.at(0) < left.at(0)) {
            final.push_back(right.at(0));
            right.erase(remove(right.begin(), right.end(), right.at(0)), right.end());
        }
    }
}

void sort(vector<int> &vec) {
    int n = vec.size();

    // BASE CASE
    if (n <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    // GENERAL CASE / RECURSIVE CASE
    vector<int> leftVec;
    vector<int> rightVec;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i < n / 2) {
            leftVec.push_back(vec.at(i));
        } else {
            rightVec.push_back(vec.at(i));
        }
    }

    sort(leftVec);
    sort(rightVec);
    vec.clear();
    merge(vec, leftVec, rightVec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `vec` have been copied to `leftVec` and `rightVec` before the `clear` call, so no information has been lost. You haven't given the source for `merge` but we can assume it copies the contents back into `vec`.

Comment: Just added the contents of merge.

Comment: So I see now how the contents are copied back into vec through merge() , thanks. I guess I am still trying to wrap my mind around how this all works with recursion here and pass by reference. Any suggestions? I've opened the debugger and walked through, but I'm not all the way there yet.

Comment: @eb80 the recursive step of the algorithm is much easier to understand if you *don't* think about the merge step. It should be fairly straight forward. [`std::merge()`] helps a ton. See a hopefully-simple  basic iterator-based version [here](http://ideone.com/bPT2HK). `std::inplace_merge()` make the entire algorithm virtually [even more trivial](http://ideone.com/Ayt5jq), as then literally *all* you provide is the partitioning.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I opened up my stackframe viewer in my debugger and when "vec.clear();" is called, it only seems to clear the value of vector in that stackframe and now stackframes further down. Wouldn't the pass-by-reference nature of this function cause it to clear the values in the vector everywhere since they get wiped out?

Comment: @eb80 the vector you're "clearing" is only one stack frame above the call. Remember, a `vec.clear()` will clear whatever was passed in, but what was passed in is the original vector in only *one* case: the very top invocation. The rest are temporaries (`leftVec` and `rightVec`) each from an upper stack frame.